# ```bash: xterm: command not found``` when running Python, Sublime Text 3 (Mac)

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

I want to run Python Code on Sublime Text 3. I did this in order to run programs that require inputs from the user.

1- I installed "PackageResourceViewer"

2- In the command palette I typed and selected "PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource"

3- Then I wrote python and selected the first item in the result list (Python)

4- In the pop-up panel I chose Python.sublime-build

5- The opened file I wrote the following lines of code:

```
"shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        },

        {
            "name": "Run in console",
             "osx":{
                "shell_cmd": "xterm -hold -e python -u \"$file\""
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

I type Shift-Cmd-B, select Python and get the following error on the terminal:

```
bash: xterm: command not found
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: xterm -hold -e python -u "/Users/kalebsamano/Desktop/Fun. Programacion/calculadora_ahorros.py"]
[dir: /Users/kalebsamano/Desktop/Fun. Programacion]
[path: /anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I'm using MacOS

Comment: MacOS doesn't have `xterm` installed by default (or at least, mine doesn't); have you installed something that provides it?

Comment: What is ```xterm```? I'm not familiarized with the term nor the error that pops up. But I think I haven't install something related.

Comment: `xterm` is a terminal emulator for the X windowing system. MacOS doesn't use that windowing system, so it doesn't ship with `xterm` either. There used to be an X server for MacOS, which might also include `xterm` if it still exists. If not, you need to use a different terminal emulator instead.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you have any ideas of another terminal emulator that I can use?

Comment: Not off the top of my head; I use `iTerm` as my terminal program, but I don't know if it (or the default MacOS terminal) can be used for something like this. You can use the [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) package to run interactive programs directly within Sublime, though (see for example [this video excerpt](https://www.screencast.com/users/OdatNurd/folders/Sublime%20Text/media/6b7ab7c1-2c19-421c-b3b1-f7cf8b7c3338)). That may be a better way to go overall. I can write up an answer for you based on that if that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Download XQuartz from the XQuartz web : https://www.xquartz.org and install XQuartz. This solves my problem.